# How do I start a new playthrough if I want my autosaves to remain saved?

Tags: dishonored

Do I go with "New Game" and use manual saves, or just replay missions and use manual saves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go to your old one and save manually, then choose new game. Thus saving the old and new.

Answer (score 5):

Newer autosaves will always overwrite older ones. There is no way to start a new playthrough without overwriting autosaves.